# Re-validate input for a request in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

Is there a way to ask ASP.NET to re-validate input if the input has been validated once for a request? [HttpRequest.ValidateInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.validateinput.aspx) doesn't seem to help.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
string Foo(HttpRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var form = request.Form; // @1
        // ...do something with form...
    }
    catch (HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        // ...handling...
        // then re-flag validation
        request.ValidateInput(); // @2
    }

    return request.Form["comment"]; // @3
}
```

Suppose that a form is submitted containing a form field with HTML content that will fail ASP.NET's input validation. When `Form` collection is accessed (@1), ASP.NET will throw `HttpRequestValidationException`. The `catch` handler, however, requests validation again (@2). Per docs, [ValidateInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.validateinput.aspx) does not take effect immediately. Instead, it flags validation to take place next time guarded bits of the request (like the `Forms` collection) are accessed. However, no exception is raised when the `Form` collection is accessed again (@3).

Comment: Why you want to re-validate the same input again?

Comment: Admittedly, the code above doesn't illustrate a practical case so here's a more realistic scenario. Suppose you want to log each form post. Suppose further, you want to log on a best-effort basis. If HttpRequestValidationException occurs as a result of accessing the Forms collection during logging then you want to just move along. However, if you don't re-request validation then application code that tries to access the collection later may be open to XSS attacks.

Comment: this would depend upon the purpose of logging. If its for simple diagnostic purposes then you can log raw values from post request. Unfortunately, the input validation logic is flag based. Flag can be set either via config or via manually by calling ValidateInput - but once set it does not get cleared. Validation happens on-demand (only when access is made) and selective (cookies, forms etc get validated separately) but once done, it cannot be re-triggered. You probably need to build your own validation logic.

Comment: You can already build your own validation logic by registering a subclass of RequestValidator but even that validator will only be called once during a request. As you noted, the flagging cannot be reset. Dumping raw values for Forms is not very helpful unless you decode the input MIME type. I've managed to hack a solution that resets the validation flags via private reflection but I was hoping for something more official. Apparently, MVC3 is able to pull it off but also via private reflection.